# Cash Signup Bonuses from Credit Cards

Tags: credit-card

I see that there are some sign up bonus deals from Chase and Capital One right now that offer you $100 if you spend $500 in 3 months.

I was curious to know if these are generally a check, or if they are a debit to your account.

If it is a debit to your account, and you pay off the $500 in whole before the debit occurs, do you simply see a +$100 debit when they decide to grant it to you, at which point you may then buy $100 worth of goods?

Comment: You'd have to ask them, but I would expect they credit to your account -- because that not only costs them nothing, but earns them a small percentage back in processing fees paid by the businesses that accept the card. NOTE: Check the exact terms of the card before signing up; if they're paying this much to get you to take it, it's probably one of the worse deals in terms of interest rates, grace periods, fees, and so on.

Comment: @keshlam what doo you mean costs them nothing? It costs them $100.

Comment: Credit to your account costs them nothing to _process_. Cutting a check adds printing and postage, which adds up when there are enough people.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the sign-up bonuses I've gotten, unless they specify that they give "points", are statement credits.  So yeah, you'll just have a $100 credit on your account that you can then spend.